# Deserialize based on Child Class Apex Type

Tags: json, deserialize

I am trying to deserialize a a serialized string of a child class from a static method.

I have tried referenced the childClass from the static method, but it can't find it because it's a static method, I have tried referencing the child class as I normally would, but the syntax is wrong. I'm unable to find an example in the documentation of doing this directly. I know it's possibly I could create a new class and reference that so I could directly deserialize by Apex type myChildClass, but I would like to do this without creating a new class if possible.

### Invoking Class

```
public class otherClass {
    myClass.myChildClass instanceOfChildClass = new myClass.myChildClass(); 
    instanceOfChildClass.myString = 'Test';
    instanceOfChildClass.myMap = myMap.put('testKey','testValue');
    myClass.myMethod(JSON.serialize(instanceOfChildClass));
}
```

### Apex Type & Deserializing Method

```
public class myClass {
    
    public class myChildClass {
        String myString {get;set;}
        Map<String,string> myMap {get;set;}
    }
     
    public static String myMethod (String serializedMyChildClass) {
        // I want to deserialze using myChildClass
        myClass deserialization = (myClass)JSON.deserialize(serializedMyChildClass, myClass.myChildClass.class);
       return deserialization.myChildClass.myString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong type:

```
    myClass deserialization = (myClass)JSON.deserialize(serializedMyChildClass, myClass.myChildClass.class);
```

Should be:

```
    myClass.myChildClass deserialization = (myClass.myChildClass)JSON.deserialize(serializedMyChildClass, myClass.myChildClass.class);
```